# Is it good idea to take user id from SecurityContextholder in spring boot RestController..?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session

I am developing spring boot rest application for an ecommerce app, suppose i have endpoint **/shipping-address** which will fetch all the saved addresses for the user, is it good idea to take user id from SecurityContextHolder like

```
Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    Long userId;
    if (principal instanceof UserPrincipal) {
        userId = ((UserPrincipal) principal).getId();
    }
```

or should i pass from the client side in the request body..? which is correct..? If i take from SecurityContextHolder is it problem when it comes to Horizontal scaling..??

Please help, i am new to backend development. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the userId from the SecurityContext is a good idea because it will prevent from hacking your application.

If you pass the userId from the client somebody could intercept the request and change the userId.

In regards to scaling it depends how you authenticate the user. If it's basic or token based and does not rely on session information. Everything will be fine.

Comment: If i take from SecurityContext  is it problem when it comes to Horizontal scaling..??

Comment: As I said no as far as you don't rely on session information

Answer (score 0):

### SecurityContext

There is no problem in using a SecurityContext with Spring MVC.

You could use something like :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/auth")
@Slf4j
public class AuthResource {

    @GetMapping(path = "whoami", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    public ResponseEntity<String> whoami(@AuthenticationPrincipal() UserDetails userDetails) {
        String login = userDetails.getUsername();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(login);
    }

}
```

The annotation [`@AuthenticationPrincipal`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-authentication-principal) from Spring Security will simplify your code.

### Session storage

By default, the session will be backed by the HttpSession (cookie JSESSIONID).
So you'll need something like sticky sessions if using a load balancer.

However, sessions can be stored elsewhere, like in relational databases (JDBC) or in Redis : this is what [**Spring Session**](https://spring.io/projects/spring-session) can do.

See also [Control the Session with Spring Security](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session).

You can also choose to not use sessions with Spring Security :

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
```